# How to implement Alghoritm for SpMV (sparse matrix product)

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I wrote a Compressed Diagonal Storage (Sparse Matrix class) [pag. 25](https://www.it.uu.se/education/phd_studies/phd_courses/pasc/lecture-1) 
this storage use :

- Matrix `(n , n_diag)` in which the non zero diagonal are stored
- a vector dimension `n_diag` that stored the off-set of each non zero diag in the matrix.

For achieve this I used a

`map<int , std::vector<data_type>>  value`

and :

`std::set<int>  diag`

diag contain the off-set of the diagonal that is the key of the map .

I'm don't understand what I'm wrong in the algorithm of Matrix vector Product 
reported in the follows pictures :

[image]

and here :

[image]

I wrote the class and the algorithm as follow :

```
# include <initializer_list>
# include <iomanip>
# include <iostream>
# include <cassert>
# include <cmath>
# include <vector>
# include <string>
# include <set>
# include <algorithm>
# include <map>
# include <exception>

# define __TESTING__

template<typename T>
class DIAmatrix;


template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DIAmatrix<U>& m );

//- SpMV
//
template<typename U>
std::vector<U> operator*(const DIAmatrix<U>& , const std::vector<U>& ) ;


template<typename Type >
class DIAmatrix 
{
    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DIAmatrix<U>& m );

     //- SpMV
     //
     template<typename U>
     friend std::vector<U> operator*(const DIAmatrix<U>& , const std::vector<U>& ) ;


  public:

     constexpr DIAmatrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<Type>> ) ;

     Type& operator()(const std::size_t , const std::size_t ) noexcept ;

      auto constexpr printDIA() const noexcept ; 


    private:

      std::size_t denseRows ;
      std::size_t denseCols ;

      mutable Type dummy    ;

      std::size_t nnz ;

      std::size_t dim ;      

      std::map<int ,  std::vector<Type>> value ;   // value 
      std::set<int>                        dig ;   // off-diagonal distance

      Type constexpr findValue(const std::size_t , const std::size_t ) const noexcept ;
};

//-------       implemantation      ------- //

template<typename T>
constexpr DIAmatrix<T>::DIAmatrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> rows )  
{
    denseRows = rows.size();
    denseCols = (*rows.begin()).size(); 

    if(denseRows != denseCols )
    {
       throw std::runtime_error("DIA-Matrix , SIZE EXCEPTION THROWN :\n>>> Matrix Must be square! <<<");   
    }

    dim = denseRows ;

    value[0].resize(dim);
    value[1].resize(dim-1);       // diagonal 
    value[-1].resize(dim-1);      // tri-bands as default

    dig.insert(-1);
    dig.insert(0);                // tribands as default 
    dig.insert(1);


    auto i =0 , j=0 ;  
    for(auto row : rows )
    {
       j=0;     
       for(auto val : row )
       {
         if(val != 0)
         {
                if( i==j )   value[0].at(i) = val  ;
           else if(j==i-1)   value[-1].at(j) = val  ; 
           else if(j==i+1)   value[1].at(i) = val ;
           else if(j < i )
           {
              auto offset =  j-i ; 
              if( !(dig.find(offset) != dig.end()) )
              {
                  dig.insert(offset);
                  value[offset].resize(dim-(fabs(j-i)));
                  value[offset].at(j) = val ;
              }
              else
                  value[offset].at(j) = val ; 
           }
           else if(j > i)
           {
             auto offset = j-i ;
             if( !(dig.find(offset) != dig.end())) 
             {     
                 dig.insert(offset);
                 value[offset].resize(dim-(fabs(j-i))); 
                 value[offset].at(i) = val ; 
             }
             else
               value[offset].at(i) = val;
           }
         }
         j++;
       }
       i++;
    }
#  ifdef __TESTING__
      printDIA();
#  endif
}


template<typename T>
T constexpr DIAmatrix<T>::findValue(const std::size_t r, const std::size_t c) const noexcept 
{
    T val = 0.0;  
    if( value.find(c-r) != value.end() )  
       val  = r < c ? value.at(c-r).at(r) : value.at(c-r).at(c) ;      
    return val ;     
}


template<typename T>
auto constexpr DIAmatrix<T>::printDIA() const noexcept 
{

   auto it = dig.begin() ; 

   for( auto& n : dig)
    { 
      std::cout << std::setw(4) <<*it << " | :  " ;
      for(auto& x : value.at(n) )
      {
         std::cout << x << " " ;   
      }
      ++it ;
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& DIAmatrix<T>::operator()(const std::size_t r, const std::size_t c) noexcept 
{
      assert( r >0 && r <= dim && c > 0 && c <= dim ) ;
      dummy = findValue(r-1,c-1);
      return dummy ;
}


template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DIAmatrix<U>& m )
{
      for(auto i=1; i <= m.denseRows ; i++ )
      {
          for(auto j=1 ; j <= m.denseCols ; j++) 
          {
               os << std::setw(6) << m(i,j) << " ";   
          }
          os << std::endl;  
      }
}



template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const DIAmatrix<T>& m, const std::vector<T>& x ) 
{
    std::vector<T> y(x.size());

    if(m.denseCols != x.size())
    {
       throw std::runtime_error("Erorr size of matrix and vector doesn't match!");
    }
    else
    {
      // for(auto i=0; i< x.size() ; i++ )
          for(auto offset : m.dig )
          {
            for(auto j = 0 ; j < m.value.at(offset).size() ; j++ )
            {
                 y.at(j) += m.value.at(offset).at(j) * x.at(j+fabs(offset))  ;
            }
         }
      // }  
       //}
    }
    return y;
}
```

the main function is :

```
# include "DiaMatrix.H"

using namespace std;

int main() {

   DIAmatrix<int> dm = {{11,12,0,0,0,0,0,0} ,{0,22,0,0,0,0,0,0} ,{31,32,33,0,0,0,0,0},
                              {41,42,43,44,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,55,56,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,66,67,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,77,78},{0,0,0,0,0,0,87,88}};

     cout << dm ;

    std::vector<int> v1 = {3,4,0,1,6,8,1,19};


    vector<int> v2 = dm * v1 ; 

   for(auto& x : v2)
     cout << x << ' ' ;
   cout << endl;   


  return 0;
}
```

that give me the wrong result :

```
122 130 43 44 778 595 3212 1672
```

instead of the right one :

```
81 88 221 335 778 595 1559 1759
```

(calculate using octave)

the strange think is that using Fortran I wrote the same method and it works correctly :

```
       MODULE DIA

      IMPLICIT NONE


CONTAINS 
!----------------------------------------------------------------------      
      SUBROUTINE SpMV( diag , n_diag, offset , n , y, x )
      IMPLICIT NONE 

       INTEGER , INTENT(IN)                      :: n_diag, n     
       INTEGER , INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(n,n_diag) :: diag 
       INTEGER , INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(n)        :: x 
       INTEGER , INTENT(INOUT),DIMENSION(n)      :: y
       INTEGER , INTENT(IN) ,DIMENSION(n_diag)   :: offset           
       INTEGER                       :: i,j , tmp

       DO i=1,n
         tmp = 0 
         DO j = 1, n_diag

           tmp = tmp + diag(i,j) * x(i+offset(j))
         ENDDO   
         y(i) = tmp   
      ENDDO
      END SUBROUTINE

      END MODULE 
!------------------------------------------------------------------------
      PROGRAM main 
       USE DIA      
       IMPLICIT NONE 
       INTEGER            :: i
       INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m=8 , ndiag=5
       INTEGER, DIMENSION (ndiag)   :: ofs=(/-3,-2,-1,0,1/) 
       INTEGER, DIMENSION (m)       :: yy 
       INTEGER, DIMENSION (m)       :: xx = (/3,4,0,1,6,8,1,19/)
       INTEGER ,DIMENSION (m,ndiag) ::val=RESHAPE((/0,0,0,41,0,0,0,0,&
     &                                              0,0,31,42,0,0,0,0,&
     &                                              0,0,32,43,0,0,0,87,&
     &                                         11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,&
     &                                        12,0,0,0,56,67,78,0/),&
     &                                        SHAPE=(/m,ndiag/))

      CALL SpMV( val , ndiag, ofs , m , yy, xx ) 

      WRITE(6,FMT='(8I5)') (yy(i), i=1,m) 

      END PROGRAM
```

Ok I've got the problem ! first of all the method should be change in this way :

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const DIAmatrix<T>& m, const std::vector<T>& x ) 
{
    std::vector<T> y(x.size());

    if(m.denseCols != x.size())
    {
       throw std::runtime_error("Erorr size of matrix and vector doesn't match!");
    }
    else
    {
       for(auto i=0; i< x.size() ; i++ )
       {
        for(auto j = m.dig.begin() ; j != m.dig.end() ; j++ )
            {
               if( i < m.value.at(*j).size() )   
               {   
                 auto index = (i + *j) >= 0 ? (i + *j) : 0 ;   
                        y.at(i) += m.value.at(*j).at(i) * x.at(index) ;
               }
            }
         }
      }
    return y;
}
```

but here the problem persist because the

`map<int,std::vector<T>>` have no the same dimension for all the diagonal.
in particular each diagonal have size :

`size_of_diagonal - fabs(diagonal_offset)`

if the offset is negative the loop have to consider `fabs(diagonal_offset)` 0 before the start of the vector contained in the map , otherwise (if the offset is positive ) the diagonal should add `n` 0 at the end , where `n` is the offset! but I don't know how to achieve this !

**EDIT**
I've fixed the problem with this horrible solution how can improve it ??:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const DIAmatrix<T>& m, const std::vector<T>& x ) 
{
    std::vector<T> y(x.size());

    if(m.size2() != x.size())
    {
       std::string to = "x" ;
       std::string mess = "Error occured in operator* attempt to perfor productor between op1: "
                        + std::to_string(m.size1()) + to + std::to_string(m.size2()) +
                        " and op2: " + std::to_string(x.size());
       throw InvalidSizeException(mess.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        for(auto j = m.dig.begin() ; j != m.dig.end() ; j++ )
        {   

             std::vector<T> vet(x.size());
             for(auto i=0; i< x.size() ; i++ )
             {
               vet.clear();

               if( *j < 0 )
               {
                  for(auto k=0 ; k < fabs(*j); k++ )
                     vet.push_back(0);
                  for(auto k=0 ; k< m.value.at(*j).size() ; k++ )
                     vet.push_back(m.value.at(*j).at(k));    
               }
               if(*j == 0)
               {
                 for(auto k=0 ; k< m.value.at(*j).size() ; k++ )
                     vet.push_back(m.value.at(*j).at(k));   
               }
               if(*j > 0)
               {
                 for(auto k=0 ; k< m.value.at(*j).size() ; k++ )
                     vet.push_back(m.value.at(*j).at(k));   
                 for(auto k=0 ; k < fabs(*j); k++ )
                     vet.push_back(0);
               }

               auto index = (i + *j) >= 0 ? (i + *j) : 0 ;   
                    y.at(i) += vet.at(i) * x[index] ;

            }
            //std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

**EDIT** : Solved

I solved with a redesign of the whole class, basically I always construct the diagonal of fixed size and so I change the constructor in this way :

```
template<typename T>
constexpr DIAmatrix<T>::DIAmatrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> rows )  
{
    denseRows = rows.size();
    denseCols = (*rows.begin()).size(); 

    if(denseRows != denseCols )
    {
       throw std::runtime_error("DIA-Matrix , SIZE EXCEPTION THROWN :\n>>> Matrix Must be square! <<<");   
    }

    dim = denseRows ;

    value[0].resize(dim);
    value[1].resize(dim);       // diagonal 
    value[-1].resize(dim);      // tri-bands as default

    dig.insert(-1);
    dig.insert(0);                // tribands as default 
    dig.insert(1);


    auto i =0 , j=0 ;  
    for(auto row : rows )
    {
       j=0;     
       for(auto val : row )
       {
         if(val != 0)
         {
                if( i==j )   value[0].at(i) = val  ;
           else if(j==i-1)   value[-1].at(j+1) = val  ; 
           else if(j==i+1)   value[1].at(i) = val ;
           else if(j < i )
           {
              auto offset =  j-i ; 
              if( !(dig.find(offset) != dig.end()) )
              {
                  dig.insert(offset);
                  value[offset].resize(dim);
                  value[offset].at(j+fabs(offset)) = val ;
              }
              else
                  value[offset].at(j+fabs(offset)) = val ; 
           }
           else if(j > i)
           {
             auto offset = j-i ;
             if( !(dig.find(offset) != dig.end())) 
             {     
                 dig.insert(offset);
                 value[offset].resize(dim); 
                 value[offset].at(i) = val ; 
             }
             else
               value[offset].at(i) = val;
           }
         }
         j++;
       }
       i++;
    }
#  ifdef __TESTING__
      printDIA();
#  endif
}
```

then the findValue :

```
    template<typename T>
    T constexpr DIAmatrix<T>::findValue(const std::size_t r, const std::size_t c) const noexcept 
    {
        T val = 0.0;  
        if( value.find(c-r) != value.end() )  
           val  = r < c ? value.at(c-r).at(r) : value.at(c-r).at(c-(c-r)) ;      
        return val ;     
    }

and of course the product routine 

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> operator*(const DIAmatrix<T>& m, const std::vector<T>& x ) 
{
    std::vector<T> y(x.size());

    if(m.denseCols != x.size())
    {
       throw std::runtime_error("Erorr size of matrix and vector doesn't match!");
    }
    else
    {
        for(auto j = m.dig.begin() ; j != m.dig.end() ; j++ )
        {   

             std::vector<T> vet(x.size());
             for(auto i=0; i< x.size() ; i++ )
             {
                 auto index = (i + *j) >= 0 ? (i + *j) : 0 ;   
                    y.at(i) += m.value.at(*j).at(i) * x[index] ;

             }
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```